# Retrieve saved text from MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

I have a form that saves text into the MySQL database. The user does not need to register to save that form. How do I make it so that when someone submit's a form, it will display their text that THEY typed in a saved. I want it to be able to retrieve they're text that they submitted at that time and possibly give it a link like this: http://www.example.com/text115612 (the numbers are for different texts...) and make the retrieved text display on that page?

Comment: @ThomasKilian I'm not looking for cookies. I'm looking for something that will assign it a special URL where the user can later go to that URL to view the text that they saved.

Comment: But without some sort of identification how will you relate the record/url to that specific user? Seems you would need to save cookie or ip address.

Comment: @EternalHour Can I somehow assign an ID for it? I mean MySQL already assigns an ID for each row. Can I just use that and be able to retrieve the information in that row?

Comment: You can surely assign an ID, but don't you need it associated with a particular user?

Comment: @EternalHour You're right. I don't need to assiciate it with a particular user because the form can be submitted anonymously. How do I use the already assigned ID and give it a URL right when the user submits the form?

Answer (score 0):

When the user submits the text, you can save the text together with an ID, in your example **text115612**.
After they've submitted, a server side script will redirect the user to the newly created text *(Serverside, because the user can't predict what the ID will be)*.
If you wish to make the texts a little more private, you can make a harder ID so it's not possible for people to guess it.

Comment: I know the id's of each table is automatically assigned... How can I retrieve all the information in each table in the MySQL database and assign them a special URL to view them?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is retrieve the text and create new file
with unique name

```
$userttext = $textfromdb  // get the user text
$file = fopen('text_file_name.txt','w') // open a new file
frwite($file,$textfromdb); // write to the file
fclose($file); // close the file




$link = "http://website.com/"."text_file_name.txt"; // create the website link
```

Comment: I'm not quite understanding your answer. I'm trying to retrieve the information in that row and be able to output it with a specific address (like example.com/row1). Each row would have it's own address like for row 1, it would be example.com/row1 and it would display the information in row 1 in the MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

When user submits the form, you would do something like this.

```
//insert your text//
INSERT INTO table_name (text) VALUES ('text');

//get the primary key that was just inserted//
//column must be auto-increment//
$textid = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

//you can also do this directly in PHP//
$textid = $mysqli->insert_id;

echo "http://www.example.com/" . $textid;
```